# Match elements from one list to another, skip already-matched elements, Python

Tags: python, list, text-processing

The solution to this is likely obvious to many of you, but I'm stuck so I thought I'd ask.

I have two lists in the following format:

```
target_list =['apples 1', 'oranges 1', 'bananas 2', 'apples 3', 'oranges 2','mango 3', 'apples 2']
source_list =  ['A apples', 'B mango', 'C apples', 'D bananas', 'E oranges','F apples', 'G oranges']
```

I need to loop through each of the `target_items` in `target_list` and, if the `target_item()[0]` is a match to an `source_item()[1]` in `source_list`, `return target_item()[0],source_item()[0], target_item()[1]`.  It's essential that there be no repeats of source_item/target_item pairs in the output,

Here is what I mean. Suppose I use a regular old for-loop:

```
for target_item in target_list:
        for source_item in source_list: 
                if source_item.split()[1] == target_item.split()[0]: 
                        print target_item.split()[0], source_item.split()[0],  target_item.split()[1]
```

The (incorrect) output I get is:

```
apples A 1
apples C 1
apples F 1
oranges E 1
oranges G 1
bananas D 2
apples A 3
apples C 3
apples F 3
oranges E 2
oranges G 2
mango B 3
apples A 2
apples C 2
apples F 2
```

Notice that the source/target pairs apple A, apples C, apples F is repeated 3 times each time with different numbers.  The same is true of the oranges pairs.  What I need instead is

```
apples A 1
apples C 2
apples F 3
oranges E 1
oranges G 2
bananas D 2
mango B 3
```

I.e., each entry should always have a different source and target.

Also, for each set of 'apple $ LETTER' and'orange $LETTER' pairs, it doesn't matter if the number tags are permuted differently. So, the following is equally good output:

```
apples A 2
apples C 1
apples F 3
oranges E 2
oranges G 1
bananas D 2
mango B 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
target_list =['apples 1', 'oranges 1', 'bananas 2', 'apples 3', 'oranges 2','mango 3', 'apples 2']
source_list =  ['A apples', 'B mango', 'C apples', 'D bananas', 'E oranges','F apples', 'G oranges']

from collections import defaultdict

# you want each target fruit to be a group, so use them as keys in a dict
# use a defaultdict list so whenever you access a key that doesn't exist
# it creates an empty list at that key
td = defaultdict(list)

for item in target_list:
    key, value = item.split()
    # the value for each fruit is a list of the numbers associated with it
    td[key].append(value)

# for each source item find a match and pop a number from the list
# so that each pair gets a different number
for item in source_list:
    letter, key = item.split()
    if key in td:
        print key, letter, td[key].pop()
```